# Using re.findall but without parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, python-2.7

I have a variable in python `x`, storing below values :

```
XYZ (APABC01)
ABC (ACACA18)
GHI (ABUAD21)
```

I want only the part which is inside the parenthesis as a list.
I have used below regex and I almost got it correct :

```
re.findall('\((.*?\))',x)
```

Output is:

```
['APABC01)', 'ACACA18)', 'ABUAD21)']
```

My question is how can I eliminate the other parenthesis. I want the output like :

```
['APABC01', 'ACACA18', 'ABUAD21']
```

so that i can access my elements in the list for further usage

Comment: Change to: `re.findall('\(([^)]+)', x)`

Comment: Or just simply `[ item.replace(")", "") for item in  ['APABC01)', 'ACACA18)', 'ABUAD21)']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
import re

x = '''XYZ (APABC01)
ABC (ACACA18)
GHI (ABUAD21)
'''
print(re.findall(r'[(](.*?)[)]', x))
# ['APABC01', 'ACACA18', 'ABUAD21']
```

`[(]` : Character class that consists of only `(` - the opening parens. You can also use `\(` - escaped opening parens instead.
`(.*?)` : Any character repeated 0 or more times, non-greedy (the minimum number of occurrences). The pattern is captured and returned as a list by `re.findall`.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing the grouping first, so it is capturing the parentheses too. Try:

```
re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', x)
```

First, it escapes the parentheses and then captures everything in between.